# updating textbox in wp8 using listbox in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox, listbox

i am using a listbox to collect the data from the url and i will displaying it on text box. i need to update the textbox on run-time whenever i needed.

My Code of XAML..

```
<Grid x:Name="prayertimegrid" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="456" ShowGridLines="True" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="536" Margin="11,10,-11,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456">
                <ListBox x:Name="editprayertime" Height="584" ItemsSource="{Binding Organization, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid x:Name="prayertime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="680" Width="456" ShowGridLines="True">

                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_prayer1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="0,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="prayer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="data1" Text="{Binding data1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="100,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18"/>

                                    <TextBlock x:Name="prayer2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,131,367,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Dhuhr" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="data2" Text="{Binding data2, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="100,120,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18"/>

                                    <TextBlock x:Name="prayer3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="6,179,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="prayer3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="data3" Text="{Binding data3, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="100,170,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18"/>


                                    <Button Content="Update" x:Name="btn_updateprayertime" Height="70" Width="150" Margin="134,474,172,136" Click="btn_updateprayertime_click"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

how to update the content of the textbox...

Comment: Just update the `data1`, `data2`, or `data3` property of your model. Make sure it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: thanx.. i didnt use INotifyPropertyChanged,.. can you pleas say how to achive it.. i'm new to WP8,...

Comment: Look at this: "[Data binding for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx)"